# Android : Intent startActivity inside onCreate gives blank screen

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I checked if condition with Toast message and key.retrieveApi gives 0 but activity is not starting and I don't see any error in my log as well. Here is my code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ApiKeyDao key=new ApiKeyDao(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Toast.makeText(this, "user"+key.retrieveApi().status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(key.retrieveApi()==null) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
        else if(key.retrieveApi().getStatus()==1) //1== Existing user
        {
            Intent profile=new Intent(this,HomeFeed.class);
            startActivity(profile);
        }
        else if(key.retrieveApi().getStatus()==0) // 0= new user
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent profile=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ProfileActivity.class);
            profile.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(profile);
        }
        else
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you have 3 `setContentView` statements here, you probably only need 1

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?
Intent profile=new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class);